# Handling Errors in MVC Child Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views, child-actions

My error handling collects (some manually, some automatically) the errors produced during controller execution. Then I have a partial view which renders out the error messages. 
I store the error messages in ViewData (and transfer them to TempData if I respond in a RedirectResult).

The problem is: **if a child action causes an error it will not get displayed**, as they (at least the ones further down the page) are executed AFTER the partial view is rendered.

Right now the only, somewhat desperate idea I have is to render the messages into javascript at the bottom of the layout page, and have that javascript update the error display boxes. But it smells bad, I shouldn't need client-side code for this.

Is there a way to have a partial view "lazy rendered", after everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use `Html.Action` and store the result in a variable for each of your child action.

And when you are done, you can call your `Html.RenderPartial` for your "error panel".

```
@{
    var result = Html.Action("ChildAction"); 
}

@Html.Partial("ErrorMessages")

@result
```

And then you resume with your regular layout by placing your variables instead of calling for the action.

Comment: Great answer - this will really help us.